# VLAN configuration on an HP 2524 Switch

Tags: switch, hp

I am trying to configure VLAN on an HP 2524 switch. If I configure VLANs and plug devices into the switch, I can not access the network with these devices. I set the ports in the default VLAN to "no," and in the new VLAN to "tagged."

It doesn't matter if the IP addressing of the VLAN is set to manual, DHCP/BOOTP, or disabled. There is a correctly working DHCP server in the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most end-devices don't understand VLAN tags, because of this, access ports (those where end-devices are connected) don't normally use tags. Tags are used on trunk links to distinguish traffic in one VLAN from traffic in other VLANs.

Tag on trunk ports, not access ports.

Comment: If you want a device to be on a particular VLAN, set that VLAN to untagged on that port.

Comment: I have now changed my configuration and set the output-port to untagged, but scince my input port is used in multiple vlans it has to be tagged. The switch itself is getting a correct ip-address from the dhcp server. how should i manage ip addressing in the vlan? But already Thanks for your help

Comment: Protocols above OSI layer-4 (e.g. DHCP) are explicitly off-topic here, but you basically need to configure DHCP scopes for each VLAN for which you want DHCP. You will need some sort of DHCP relay, unless you have a DHCP server on each VLAN.